# unity3d,изменение скорости, направления rigidbody скриптом C3

Tags: c#, unity3d

Объект rigidbody движется вот этим скриптом:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) //если нажат пробел
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
```

Мне нужно при: `if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space));`
изменить направление, скорость.

пробую вот так: `rb.velocity = new Vector3(5,-1 0, 0);` - объект принимает эту команду еще в первом случае.

Пытался через `rb.useGravity = false/true`, объект вообще не движется.
как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте текст вопроса. Плохо читается

Comment: В плане скорость? Медленнее,быстрее?

Comment: быстрее. Это птичка парит, надо чтобы пикировала

Answer (score 1):

`gameObject.transform.forward` - вектор направления игрока.
Если сделать так - `rigidbody.velocity += transform.forward * speed;` то игрок будет двигаться только вперёд по отношению к себе (Локально - Local).

Так же присутствует: `Vector3.forward` не путать с `transform.forward`, первое - глобальное.